# How can to get $v(t)$ out of this acceleration graph?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, calculus

How can I get v(t) out of this acceleration graph?

Comment: Area under the graph. Note it’s zero for the middle interval, and negative in the third.

Answer (score 1):

$$a(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}v(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
$$\implies v(t)=\int a(t)\,\mathrm{d}t+C$$
If you would like to use explicit limits of integration, consider the particle at two times $t_1$ and $t_2$. Then, we can separate and integrate both sides:
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}a(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{v(t_1)}^{v(t_2)}\,\mathrm{d}v(t)=v(t_2)-v(t_1)$$

Comment: How do I apply the information I get from the graph to this equation?

Comment: To start, use $a(t)=1$ for $0<t<3$.